# Run script only on click on button instead with open the sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Currently the following script runs with opening the Google Sheet table. I want to have that the script should only run with a click of a button. How can I do that?

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim() || "";
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

Comment: did you set up an onOpen trigger by any chance?

Comment: I didnt set up anything. I just put in this script in the script editor and it runs by open the sheets.

Comment: Is this the only function in your project? Do you have any installable triggers viewable on the [project triggers console](https://script.google.com/home/triggers)? Do you have any formulae in the Sheet that you're opening?

Comment: Yes, this is the only function in my project and there is no triggers on the project triggers console but yeah, I use the function with
`=WENNFEHLER(getStatusCode(G3);"Not Found")`
for all cells in a column. Is this the problem? And if yes, how can I do that better?

Comment: as far as I know this script as standalone wont run upon opening unless you change `function getStatusCode(url){` to `function onOpen(url){` therefore only thing that runs this script is your WENNFEHLER formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Rather than using the `=IFERROR`<sup>*</sup> formula, you can make the function set the value for your cell rather than return.*

#### Code:

Make sure to change the range of cells containing your URLs and the range of cells that have `=IFERROR()` formula in. In this example script they are in column `G` and `H` respectively.

```
function getStatusCode(){
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'followRedirects': false
  };
  // this is the range of cells containing your WENNFEHLER formula
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("H1:H100");
  
  // this is the range of urls
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("G1:G100");
  
  var newValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < range.getValues().length; i++) {
    var url_trimmed = range2.getValues()[i][0].trim() || "";    
    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
      newValues.push([response.getResponseCode()]);
    }
    catch(e) {
      newValues.push(["Not found"]);
    }
  }
  range.setValues(newValues);  
}
```

#### Assigning to a Button:

Now, you can create an in-sheet button which will run the script whenever you click it.

1. Go to the `Insert > Drawing` menu item and create a shape; any shape will do, this will act as your button.
2. Press `Save and Close` to add this to your sheet.
3. Move the newly-added drawing to where you would like. In the top-right of the drawing, you will see the vertical ellipsis menu (`⋮`). Click this, and then click `Assign script`.
4. In the new window, type `getStatusCode` and press `OK`.

Now, each time you click the button, the script will run. As it sets the cell value rather than being called from a formula, it will no longer run on opening the Sheet.

<sub>** Translation note: `WENNFEHLER` means `IFERROR`*</sub>

Comment: Ok thank you!
I replaced my script with yours. My `IFERROR` formula was in column F and started with cell F3, so I changed `range` to `getRange("F3:F100")`. What should I do now to run the script?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain how to make a drawing and run it :)

Comment: Ok, cool! It seems to work now for the first 100 cells – I test it now for 600 cells and this need time I think. There is still the alert "Script running".  I have a last question. I need this same function for several columns in this sheet. In which way I should extend the script you wrote for that? Really thank you for your help – it saves my day :)

Comment: You might start to run into execution time issues if you have so many columns as Apps Scripts have [execution time limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). Could you share a sanitised copy of your Sheet so to have a look?

Comment: Thank you very much! One last thing I need is that I have to check several columns not just one. How can I expand this script to do that?

Comment: Hi @johny! As this is a different question to your original I suggest you [ask it as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - stackoverflow questions/answers are designed for attacking one problem at a time and additional questions should be segregated out to help users with similar problems pinpoint the parts they need specifically :)

Comment: Hey, I think it is the same question the only thing I need now is to expand the script to run it for several columns not just one. The script is the same.

Example: In your example code I can only check cells in one column but I need this same check for four columns. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, but your original question was actually about running a script on button and not on open. This has been addressed (the script was running because you were using a formula to get its return). If you want to do this now for multiple columns the script has to be edited away from what the original question wanted to get done, and by increasing the range of checked values you may start to hit new errors such as [script execution time limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) which are all best addressed as a new question.