# How can I not execute a function at open a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-custom-function

I made a function on google sheets that make a request for an external link. I call the function as this:

```
=functionimade(params)
```

But, always I open the sheet, the funtion is called and the request made. How can I solve it? I want to make the request once

Comment: read: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this isn't possible to do.*

#### More Information:

When a custom function is called in a Sheet, the value of the cell the return of the function - it's the formula that calls it. The return value of the function is calculated each time the Sheet is opened because the only thing that was saved was the formula; not the data.

Also, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services), custom functions do not support the `.set*()` methods of `SpreadsheetApp`:

> **Spreadsheet Service:** Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).

This means that it isn't possible to instead set the value of the cell directly using `.getRange(cell).setValue(functionimade(params))` as the scope of custom functions do not allow you to set it directly.

#### Workaround:

At the end of your function, rather than returning the value, you can set the contents with the aforementioned `.setValue()` method, only you will have to specify the cell in the function itself:

```js
function functionimade(params) {
  var myReturnValue = // some cool code here

  var cell = 'A1'; // << change this
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(cell)
                                                        .setValue(myReturnValue);
}
```

#### References:

- [Custom functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class `Range` | Apps Script - Method `.setValue(value)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

---

#### Related Questions:

- [Run script only on click on button instead with open the sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947799)

Comment: If I try to setValue of the cell I insert the formula, it says I can't because of "Circular dependency". If I try to setValue of other cell, it says I don't have permission to do it

Comment: You can't do this with a formula at all, Sheets doesn't allow it. You don't need to use a formula with the workaround, instead whichever cell you want to set to the value, assign the A1 notation of it as a string to `cell`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there any way to execute the script without go to Tools > Script editor? A way for user that don't want to see codes (Like a button )

Comment: Check out the answer to the linked Related Question at the end of my answer - it explains how to assign a script to a button in a sheet.