# Create action buttons Search and New Record in Google Sheets Windows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

Hi I have a google sheets doc with about 11 tabs. I want to create a search function on the first sheet (Search tab) and have it search all sheets for matching records. It will be based on one criteria which is an ID number. Search field is *Search!E3* and the ID is located in *Col A* in every other sheet.
**SEARCH** button
I want the search button to do the following:
•   perform a search on required tabs.
•   provide a fall back message if no records are found.
•   provide a method of redirectling the user to a record on a tab if a record is found. If multiple maybe a 'find next' process?

The **New Record** button will redirect the user to the **Register** tab (next blank line) for them to enter the data.
The **Clear** button I have working. Though is there any way to not have the messages pop up saying the script is working etc when they press the button?

I have attached an image and also a link to a sample file.

Hope someone can help....I am no expert and may require short simple steps. I did achieve this in excel but we are wanting to use Drive.

Many thanks in anticipation!

[the buttons and search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPKPq.png)
[sample sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11fPxq70-5B-0H4Q6dgW5cfdSDTiStrRXDfJyso1ANGA/edit?usp=sharing)

Just not sure of the best way to achieve what I am hoping to do.Limited Action Script experience and can't help online specific enough to get me through this.

Comment: This is the place to ask for tips to correct errors in your codes. If you want a brand new solution please hire someone to do your work.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions on multiple topics.- the basic rule is one topic=one problem. Also, your requirements are vague and StackOverfflow is not a free code writing service - users want to help _you_ solve problem, not solve them for you. That said, here's [how to create a button that you can assign to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949201/1330560), and [Simple search through all sheets in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42034953/1330560). Your biggest problem is `Limited Action Script experience` and only you can resolve this.